# Conditional compilation error in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

This code isn't working due to Error that I couldn't get which is :

- Expected ‘)’
- type specifier missing default to ‘int’
- Expected parameter declaration
- conflicting types or ’NSLog'

this error only appear in line 4

please help thanks,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#define SYS
#ifdef SYS
    NSLog (@"SYS is Define ");
#endif


#define minimum(x,y) (x < y ? x:y)
#define Lower_case(x) ((x>'a') && (x<'z'))
#define ToUper_case(x) ((x-'a')+'A')
#define Uper_case(x) (Lower_case(x) ? (x-'a')+'A':x)

@interface NewDef : NSObject

@end
```

Comment: Is line 4 this one - `NSLog (@"SYS is Define ");`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a code statement:

```
NSLog (@"SYS is Define ");
```

which is not inside any method/function. This is not allowed in (Objective-)C(++).

You can probably achieve what you wish using:

```
#pragma message "SYS is Define "
```

This is a compile-time instruction, just as `#define` is, to the compiler to (somehow) present a message. In Xcode if this line is reached it will be marked with a warning icon:

[image]

If you comment out the `#define SYS` then the mark will go away as the line is no longer reached:

[image]

HTH